# How can I fix CA2100 Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, optimization, code-analysis

I am analyzing my code and got this security issue:

> CA2100 Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities The query string passed to 'SqlDataAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(string, SqlConnection)' in 'Add_item.loadgrid()' could contain the following variables 'Login.dbName'. If any of these variables could come from user input, consider using a stored procedure or a parameterized SQL query instead of building the query with string concatenations. Login   Add_item.cs 64

This is the highlighted code:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Newjob FROM [" + Login.dbName + "].newjob", connection. conn );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is commonly known as a SQL Injection vulnerability.  Instead of concatenating values into a string and passing that string to the SQL Server, you should use sqlParameter objects.