# OracleCommand Parameter with concatenation

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, parameters, connection

THIS works:

```
OracleCommand cm = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("select s,e from {0}" + ".DTREE where DATAID=:pDataId", credentialsthing.dbschema");
cmd.Parameters.Add("pDataId", objectx.theid);
```

However... I also want to put the first one in the parametr command:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select s,e from :pPar1" + ".DTREE where DATAID=:pDataId");
cmd.Parameters.Add("pPar1", credentialsthing.dbschema);
cmd.Parameters.Add("pDataId", objectx.theid);
```

And this fails. Why, what should the syntax be?

Comment: Stick to your first code sample.  You can't do parameter binding with the table name in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Ah yes, So CA2100 Review SQL queries for security vulnaribilities stinks. Code Analysis Code Analysis Code Analysis zzz. Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851722/how-can-i-fix-ca2100-review-sql-queries-for-security-vulnerabilities-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *can't* parameterize your table name, column name or any other database objects.

You can only parameterize your values. That's why you need to use string concatenation for your table name.

But you should be *very* careful doing that, you need to supply strong validation for your table name or should use a whitelist of some form.